# ¿Cómo usar múltiples fondos con CSS?

Tags: css

Quiero utilizar una imagen de fondo (un gif con transparencia) y un color. Esto funciona bien pero en Chrome para Android no se muestra el fondo de la imagen.

Este es mi código `scss` donde tengo el problema.

```
body {
  background: url('../img/x.gif'), $fondo;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  @media(max-width: 768px) {
    background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

He intentado con

```
background-color: $fondo;
background-image: url('../img/glitch_gopher.gif');
```

Funciona bien en desktop, en incluso funciona bien con el "emulador" de dispositivos de las herramientas de desarrollo del explorador. El problema es que no está funcionando en dispositivos móviles reales.

Comment: ¿Dónde estás definiendo `$fondo`?¿cuál es el valor que contiene?

Comment: Aparte, ¿te has planteado que el problema no sea que android no permita imágenes+colores de fondo, sino que android no soporta variables css (hasta las últimas versiones) y por lo tanto el código de arriba no va a funcionar en muchas versiones de android por ello?

Comment: Ah claro. Me faltó aclarar. Ese es código scss, la variable es un hexadecimal.